# No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am getting the error in the following code:

> "No mapping exists from object type `System.Int32[]` to a known managed provider native type."

Here `listid` is a list of `integers`.

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str1);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from status where uid in {@values}", cn);

    cn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@values", listid.ToArray());

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // code here
    }
```

Comment: [From what I know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029833/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-string-to-a-known-managed-provider-n) you can't pass an array as a SQL parameter. Have you seen it work otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your query to:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    String.Format("SELECT * FROM status WHERE uid IN ({0})",
                  String.Join(",", listid))
);
```

and remove the `AddWithValue()` line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help sir.. it worked after "cn" into your answer. :)

Comment: I've been trying to add a list of ints to a SQL string for about an hour now, and it amazes me that this is the only seemingly workable way to do it. Microsoft champion the correctness of certain methodologies in C#, yet there are often exceptions which catch you out.

Comment: I don't this will prevent sql injection. You are directly inserting the values.